# How this number to english words code works, Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, methods, integer

So when looking for a method that would be able to take an integer and return the string value of that integer, I found this solution:

```
   def in_words(int)
      numbers_to_name = {
          1000000 => "million",
          1000 => "thousand",
          100 => "hundred",
          90 => "ninety",
          80 => "eighty",
          70 => "seventy",
          60 => "sixty",
          50 => "fifty",
          40 => "forty",
          30 => "thirty",
          20 => "twenty",
          19=>"nineteen",
          18=>"eighteen",
          17=>"seventeen", 
          16=>"sixteen",
          15=>"fifteen",
          14=>"fourteen",
          13=>"thirteen",              
          12=>"twelve",
          11 => "eleven",
          10 => "ten",
          9 => "nine",
          8 => "eight",
          7 => "seven",
          6 => "six",
          5 => "five",
          4 => "four",
          3 => "three",
          2 => "two",
          1 => "one"
        }
      str = ""
      numbers_to_name.each do |num, name|
        if int == 0
          return str
        elsif int.to_s.length == 1 && int/num > 0
          return str + "#{name}"      
        elsif int < 100 && int/num > 0
          return str + "#{name}" if int%num == 0
          return str + "#{name} " + in_words(int%num)
        elsif int/num > 0
          return str + in_words(int/num) + " #{name} " + in_words(int%num)
        end
      end
    end
```

This answer is great as it provides me with an answer as to what I was trying to do. However, I am quite new and dont fully understand how it exactly works. I do understand the hash, but I do not understand how the author constructed his code below the hash. I have tried to slim this code down and test it line by line, however it doesn't work when I do that. I'm just trying to figure out why/how they are performing things like `int/num` and using their method `in_words` in the middle of their block code.

If anyone has the available time to break this down step by step and explain how this code works, I would be greatly appreciative. NOTE: I would have just commented on the original authors solution but I was not allowed to as I did not have enough 'reputation' to do so.

Comment: This should be comment on the Answer where you found that solution.

Comment: @Stephen C I can't comment on it, says "need 50 reputation to comment."

Comment: Get more reputation then :-)

Comment: I'll up-vote this question because I know how frustrating the commenting system is for new users, but it is in place for a reason (to reduce spam from those that don't participate).  I especially liked how you expressed this limitation in your question, making people aware of an effort made and not blatant disregard for the SO format.

Answer (score 3):

```
# Loop through the hash, `num` is the hash key, `name` is the hash value
numbers_to_name.each do |num, name|

   # Zero is not used in the lookup table, so return an empty string if that 
   # was an argument supplied to the function (e.g., in_words(0) )
   if int == 0
      return str

   # If it's a single digit number (e.g., `6`) and is equal to the key (e.g., 6/6 == 1)
   # then return the word/name 
   elsif int.to_s.length == 1 && int/num > 0
     return str + "#{name}"

   # If your supplied number was less than a hundred (e.g., `50`)
   elsif int < 100 && int/num > 0
      return str + "#{name}" if int%num == 0

   # If your supplied number was something like `57` you would return `fifty` and 
   # then need to convert the `7` to `seven`, so call the function 
   # again ( 57%50 has a remainder of 7, so in_words(7) translate the 7)
      return str + "#{name} " + in_words(int%num)

   # For instance, 567 => five hundred sixty seven:
    elsif int/num > 0
      return str + in_words(int/num) + " #{name} " + in_words(int%num)
    end

 end
```

---

There's a matter of recursion going on in here, which is why you see `in_words` called in multiple places.

I think an important note is the way the keys of the hash are imported (from largest to smallest).  In Ruby 1.9+, the hash keys are enumerated so that their order will be persisted.  Given the logic of your code, every time you go through the loop, it is going to accept the first key that yields a positive result.

To give an example, there are a lot of places where `int/num > 0` is used.  If your number is 6 it'll first test against 1000000.  `6/1000000` will result in `0` because numerator and denominator are both integers.  Using integers is important because `6/1000000.0` would result in a floating point number and be greater than 0 (and the if-statement would be true -- bad). That means it'll keep iterating over the keys (from input order of largest to smallest) and the first one it gets to that matches will be the one you want.

To give an example of the hash sorted in the opposite order (smallest to largest), imagine you wanted to translate 5 into a word. `5.to_s.length == 1` would be true, but then there's the `int/num > 0`.  In this case `int` is `5` and your first key would be `1`; `5 / 1` is greater than zero, so that would evaluate to true and return the value in your hash of `one`.  In other words `in_words(5)` would return `one`, which is incorrect. The hash order as found in the code (largest to smallest) would iterate over all the keys `5/10000000 ... 5/6`, which all equal 0, but then get to the first division that is greater than zero (`5 / 5 == 1`) and has the desired value.

Comment: Wow, great job. Awesome way of explaining things. This makes SO much sense now! I'm going to have to practice this a couple of times and try to master it a bit more. Also, I appreciate your patience with me and your comment above. VERY HELPFUL. So I am guessing that if I add `0 => "zero"` to the hash, it wouldn't work huh?

Comment: It wouldn't.  For one, `0/0` would result in a division by 0 error.  You could remove the first `if` statement and modify the second to `if int.to_s.length == 1 && int == num`, which would somewhat work; however, it has the problem of returning `zero` to the response when you wouldn't want it, for instance `in_words(100)` would be `one hundred zero`.  So you'd also have to do something in the last if-statement, one possibility is don't call function when there is no remainder: `return str + in_words(int/num) + " #{name} " + (int%num>0?in_words(int%num):'')`

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely quicker/cleaner ways to achieve this and the recursion is totally misguided but..

```
#loop thru all the items in the hash and assign the hey to num and val to name
numbers_to_name.each do |num, name|
    # if the input parameter is zero return str which is ""
    if int == 0
      return str

    # if the length of the string representation of the input parameter is 1 and an empty string divided by the current key is larger than 0 return str + name (this is insane)
    elsif int.to_s.length == 1 && int/num > 0
      return str + "#{name}"

    # if the key value is less than 100 and an empty string divided by the current key is larger than 0 return str + name if the modulus of key and num is 0, if not? return "" + in_words(int%num) (this is also insane)    
    elsif int < 100 && int/num > 0
      return str + "#{name}" if int%num == 0
      return str + "#{name} " + in_words(int%num)

    # if the input parameter divided by the key is larger than 0 return "" + the result of this function with the key/num as input + the current items value + in_words(int%num)
    elsif int/num > 0
      return str + in_words(int/num) + " #{name} " + in_words(int%num)
    end
  end
```

my eyes are bleeding now but that's pretty much what is going on.

Comment: Haha, I'm sure there are better ways. If you have a more 're-factored' version of this (without using things like gems) I would love to see it. I'm new so I still cant tell whether this is a productive or none productive way of going about it >.<